# Reference request: trace integral formula

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, trace

This question is *not* about the proof but about a reliable source where one can find the following formula for the normalised trace $\mbox{tr}$ of a complex $(n\times n)$-matrix:

$$\mbox{tr}(A) = \int\limits_{\|y\|=1} \langle Ax, x\rangle\, \mbox{d}m(x)$$

where $m$ is the Lebesgue (area) measure normalised to the Euclidean sphere in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Thank you.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you mean $dm(x) = \nu(x) d\lambda(x) = \frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert} d\lambda(x)$?

Comment: Yes, in other words $m$ normalises the Lebesgue measure so that the right hand side gives you 1 for $A=I$, the identity matrix.

Comment: @TomekKania: I am rather doubtful that MO is a better place for this question. Besides, the question has only been posted for 22 hours. We'll at least wait a bit before we migrate the question. (In the mean time we'll keep the flag open as a reminder.)

Comment: Also, a similar question was asked recently on MO and put on-hold, but an [existing answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/150260/3948) gives at least for a reference "Riemannian geometry" by Gallot, Hulin, and Lafontaine. The linearity of the trace implies you can split to real and imaginary parts, and the $\mathbb{C}^n$ case should follow from the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case by symmetry arguments.

Comment: @TomekKania: I have not had a chance to look at the book of Gallot, Hulin, and Lafontain. If you found that book, or the answer on MO, to be useful, I encourage you to post an answer yourself to this question with the reference you found!

Comment: The proof in this book reads as follows "Diagonalize. $\square$", so I am not sure whether this is a good answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me add some references then:

> A short proof of the fact that the matrix trace is the expectation of the numerical values, *The American Mathematical Monthly* **122** (2015), no. 8, 782–783, [arXiv version](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4272).

and a generalisation to certain other unit spheres:

> T. Kania and K. E. Morrison, The trace as an average over the unit sphere of a normed space with a 1-symmetric basis, [arXiv version](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02084).

Answer (score 3):

> Note: the following is originally due to [Bennett Chow](https://mathoverflow.net/users/41263/bennett-chow) on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150260/3948). Reposting here as CW in view of [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592416/reference-request-trace-integral-formula?noredirect=1#comment1310621_592416).

Let $S^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in some tangent space with inner product $g$. Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an orthonormal frame and let $V_i=\langle V,e_i\rangle$.
For $i\neq j$, $\int_{S^{n-1}}V_{i}V_{j}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =0$ since the
integrand is odd with respect to reflection about the coordinate hyperplane $\left\{  V_{i}=0\right\}
$. Taking $i=j$, we get $\int_{S^{n-1}}V_{i}^{2}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)
=\frac{\omega_{n}}{n}$ since this expression is independent of $i$ and since
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{S^{n-1}}V_{i}^{2}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =\int_{S^{n-1}
}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =\omega_{n}$, using $|V|^2=1$. We conclude with $\alpha_{ij}=\alpha (e_i,e_j)$ that
$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\alpha\left(  V,V\right)  \operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =\sum
_{i,j=1}^{n}\int_{S^{n-1}}\alpha_{ij}V_{i}V_{j}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{S^{n-1}}\alpha_{ii}V_{i}^{2}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)
=\frac{\omega_{n}}{n}\operatorname{Trace}{}_{g}(\alpha).
$$